# Custom style for disabled button applies to regular button also

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The key parts of the setup are similar to:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  disabledButton: {
    borderColor: "#fff"
  }
});
```

And

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  disabled
  classes={{ disabled: classes.disabledButton }}
>
  Disabled
</Button>
```

This changes the regular style of the disabled button rather than the disabled style. How can I fix this? Maybe I'm targeting the wrong class?

Comment: Would you post other relevant code as well? Or a runnable code on CodeSandbox or Stackblitz would be nice.

Comment: Thanks Sung, I'll see what I can add tomorrow. I had the whole component pasted in, but stackoverflow didn't like that and threw an error. In the mean time here's the component on github:
https://github.com/erichodges/IEX-Client/blob/master/src/modules/user/SaveQuoteList.js

Comment: Ok, I renamed the styles const, and wrapped the component using withStyles. It still does not work though. I think I'm not targeting the correct class for a disabled button.

Comment: I updated the code above, is that enough to get an idea of what I'm doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    ":disabled": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  }
});

function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
  const { classes } = props;

  const changeDisableState = () => {
    setDisable(!disable);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        disabled={disable}
        className={{dsiable: classes.button}}
      >
        Disabled
      </Button>

      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={changeDisableState}
      >
        Enable/Disable
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ContainedButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContainedButtons);
```

Comment: Cool Garry, thank you! I changed the ":disabled":  to "&:disabled": and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a style file like scss for example globalStyle.module.scss

```
.appointmentBtn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #a120d1 !important;
  }
  &:disabled {
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  }
}
```

next

```
   <Button
        variant="outlined"
        disabled={ 'your logic there' }
        className={classes.appointmentBtn}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Some text
   </Button>
```

the color of the border will be the same for any condition